# Zipped file contains multiple files. How to Read / Process them in Java Buffer in a loop

Tags: java, zip, gzipstream, gunzip

I have a Big Zipped File which in turn have 100's of small files in it. How can I unzip them (although I am doing it with GZIP already), and read into Java buffer one by one in a loop or some thing.

So basically, using GZIP I can unzip a file in Java. But how to process them, if the Zipped file has multiple files inside of it.
Thanks

```
 if (this.fiFilename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".gz")) 
     {
      // File is zipped so decode first and then read into buffer
      GZIPInputStream gZipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(this.fileInputStream);
     }
     Else
      // Normal 
      bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new          InputStreamReader(this.fileInputStream));

      // THEN PROCESS THE FILE
```

However, what happens if the Zipped file has multiple files inside it and I want to process each of them one by one?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your current code that needs fixing? Stack Overflow is not a request site.